# IE11 flickers in AJS 1.3 and need a quick fix

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

I am facing an issue of flickering screens when I toggle(on click of a search button, say for e.g.) in IE11, AngularJs 1.3 and bootstrap 3.3.5.

I am showing and hiding an element on the same bar based on certain true/false condition like this:

```html
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
                 ng-show="!vm.displayFilter">..</section>
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"
                 ng-show="!vm.displaySearch">..</section>
```

when i click on one other bumps down and then shows up on ng-show true. This happens only in IE11 and what is the fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix myself:

Adding the following in your LESS/CSS:

.ng-hide{display:none !important;}

I got to know about it from here:
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jun/02/AngularJs-ngcloak-Problems-on-large-Pages

This is an AJS flickering issue w.r.t. IE11 + AJS 1.3, when we use ng-show and hide. This seems to be fixed in AJS 1.4 recently.